# Glassfish as webserver?

Tags: java, glassfish-4

I am trying to setup glassfish as WebServer for my web application. I have installed the 
glassfish in my server and tried to upload the folder I got some error. I have another error asadmin is not recognized if I tried to access from another computer. Any body has worked previously in this issues. Please share your insights and thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: "and got some error" is not very useful if you want the error fixed.  List the error in detail.  Also, only one "question" per "question" please.

Comment: The error thrown is Archtype D:\Sample is not recognized.

Comment: An error has occured.                                        Archive type of D:\WebServiceForApp was not recognized

Comment: It sounds like you were specifying a file path instead of an archive type.  When, where, or why is not possible to answer, because while you now provide the error, there is no context in which the error was raised.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html is a good thing to read, so you can learn to get more answers, faster, for exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration of asadmin is not configured to respond to connections made from other computers.  If it were, then after starting glassfish, anybody could start trying to configure your system, including people who have access to your network that you've never even met.

You can reconfigure glassfish to expose asadmin to external connections, but if you make a mistake, you just let strangers access to your configuration interface.  That can lead to a disaster if the strangers are not friendly people.

Comment: I could figure out the problem of asadmin. I have to change the Window External Path to the example: d:/glassfish4/bin.